Extracting data of this xml to Python dataframe
I cannot get the extraction of this xml data to dataframe to work properly.
This is my xml sample. In reality I have multiple stacks of "Entity" which represent one line of data in the desired result. To save space I only pasted one instance of "Entity" here:
<EntityCollection>

  <Entities>

    <Entity>

      <Attributes>

        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

          <key>client_number</key>

          <value type="b:string">ABC123345</value>

        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

          <key>my_data.client_type</key>

          <value type="AliasedValue">

            <AttributeLogicalName>my_type</AttributeLogicalName>

            <EntityLogicalName>my_data1</EntityLogicalName>

            <NeedFormatting>true</NeedFormatting>

            <ReturnType>123</ReturnType>

            <Value type="OptionSetValue">

              <Value>345</Value>

            </Value>

          </value>

        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

          <key>my_data.status</key>

          <value type="AliasedValue">

            <AttributeLogicalName>status</AttributeLogicalName>

            <EntityLogicalName>my_data1</EntityLogicalName>

            <NeedFormatting>true</NeedFormatting>

            <ReturnType>123</ReturnType>

            <Value type="OptionSetValue">

              <Value>67</Value>

            </Value>

          </value>

        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

          <key>my_data.date</key>

          <value type="AliasedValue">

            <AttributeLogicalName>date</AttributeLogicalName>

            <EntityLogicalName>my_data1</EntityLogicalName>

            <NeedFormatting>true</NeedFormatting>

            <ReturnType>89</ReturnType>

            <Value type="b:string">2024-01-01</Value>

          </value>

        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

          <key>my_data.country</key>

          <value type="AliasedValue">

            <AttributeLogicalName>country</AttributeLogicalName>

            <EntityLogicalName>my_data1</EntityLogicalName>

            <NeedFormatting>true</NeedFormatting>

            <ReturnType>123</ReturnType>

            <Value type="OptionSetValue">

              <Value>456</Value>

            </Value>

          </value>

        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

          <key>client_code</key>

          <value type="b:guid">some_code456</value>

        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

          <key>my_data.my_data1id</key>

          <value type="AliasedValue">

           <AttributeLogicalName>my_data1id</AttributeLogicalName>

            <EntityLogicalName>my_data1</EntityLogicalName>

            <NeedFormatting>true</NeedFormatting>

            <ReturnType>13</ReturnType>

            <Value type="b:guid">some_code123</Value>

          </value>

        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>

      </Attributes>

      <EntityState nil="true"/>

      <FormattedValues>

        <KeyValuePairOfstringstring>

          <key>my_data.client_type</key>

          <value>client123</value>

        </KeyValuePairOfstringstring>

        <KeyValuePairOfstringstring>

          <key>my_data.status</key>

          <value>OK</value>

        </KeyValuePairOfstringstring>

        <KeyValuePairOfstringstring>

          <key>my_data.country</key>

          <value>some_country</value>

        </KeyValuePairOfstringstring>

      </FormattedValues>

      <Id>some_code456</Id>

      <KeyAttributes/>

      <LogicalName>some-id</LogicalName>

      <RelatedEntities/>

      <RowVersion>ID123</RowVersion>

    </Entity>

</Entities>

</EntityCollection>


The elements in 'key' (or in 'AttributeLogicalName') should be the headers. The "value"/"Value" should be the actual data. This is the desired outcome (first row).
As the data is very nested, I tried using xml.etree but did not come very far as I not sure how to proceed form here:
for _, elem in ET.iterparse(my_xml):
    if len(elem) == 0:
        print(f'{elem.tag} {elem.attrib} text={elem.text}')
    else:
        print(f'{elem.tag} {elem.attrib}')

How can I get the desired result?

Starting points here and here

Consider XSLT, to transform the nested XML for the specific entity, key and value/Value nodes. Then, use pandas to pivot by entity and due to repeated keys, suffixed numbers are added to key names. Pandas read_xml supports XSLT 1.0 using the lxml parser.
XSLT (save as .xsl file)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/EntityCollection/Entities">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Entity"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Entity">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::KeyValuePairOfstringanyType|descendant::KeyValuePairOfstringstring"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="KeyValuePairOfstringanyType|KeyValuePairOfstringstring">
    <data>
        <entity><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Entity/Id"/></entity>
        <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::key"/>
        <value><xsl:value-of select="descendant::Value[not(*)]|descendant::value[not(*)]"/></value>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

XSLT Output (long format to scale to any key and value)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <data>
      <entity>some_code456</entity>
      <key>client_number</key>
      <value>ABC123345</value>
   </data>
   <data>
      <entity>some_code456</entity>
      <key>my_data.client_type</key>
      <value>345</value>
   </data>
   <data>
      <entity>some_code456</entity>
      <key>my_data.status</key>
      <value>67</value>
   </data>
   <data>
      <entity>some_code456</entity>
      <key>my_data.date</key>
      <value>2024-01-01</value>
   </data>
   <data>
      <entity>some_code456</entity>
      <key>my_data.country</key>
      <value>456</value>
   </data>
   <data>
      <entity>some_code456</entity>
      <key>client_code</key>
      <value>some_code456</value>
   </data>
   <data>
      <entity>some_code456</entity>
      <key>my_data.my_data1id</key>
      <value>some_code123</value>
   </data>
   <data>
      <entity>some_code456</entity>
      <key>my_data.client_type</key>
      <value>client123</value>
   </data>
   <data>
      <entity>some_code456</entity>
      <key>my_data.status</key>
      <value>OK</value>
   </data>
   <data>
      <entity>some_code456</entity>
      <key>my_data.country</key>
      <value>some_country</value>
   </data>
</root>

Python (handles duplicate keys with suffixed count)
entities_df = (
    pd.read_xml("input.xml", stylesheet="style.xsl")
      .assign(key = lambda df: df["key"].str.cat(df.groupby("key").cumcount().add(1).astype('str')))
      .pivot(index="entity", columns="key", values="value")
)

Python Output
entities_df
# key           client_code1 client_number1 my_data.client_type1 my_data.client_type2  ... my_data.date1 my_data.my_data1id1 my_data.status1 my_data.status2
# entity                                                                               ...                                                                  
# some_code456  some_code456      ABC123345                  345            client123  ...    2024-01-01        some_code123              67              OK

# [1 rows x 10 columns]

